# How to make Navigation bottom bar transparent

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a transparent bottom navigation bar and here's my bottom bar part:

```
Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Theme(
                          data: Theme.of(context)
                              .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
                          child: BottomNavigationBar(
                            currentIndex: 0,
                            items: [
                              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                  title: Text('Map')),
                              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.line_style),
                                  title: Text('List')),
                              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('Add Property'))
                            ],
                          ))),
```

and this is my full `Scafold Widget`:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
      body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const SizedBox();
          } else {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  appBar(),
                  // tabBar(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                      future: getData(),
                      builder:
                          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return const SizedBox();
                        } else {
                          return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                            create: (context) => Properties(),
                            child: PropertiesGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Theme(
                          data: Theme.of(context)
                              .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
                          child: BottomNavigationBar(
                            currentIndex: 0,
                            items: [
                              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                                  title: Text('Map')),
                              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.line_style),
                                  title: Text('List')),
                              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('Add Property'))
                            ],
                          ))),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget appBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                child:
                    Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_on,
                    color: AppTheme.dark_grey,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      multiple = !multiple;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget tabBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
    );
  }
}
```

But I see that it doesn't show the page background as in the transparent bar to shown as the below image

[image: Result]

I hope some one could help me to figure out where's the problem exactly..

Comment: have you tried backgroundColor : Colors.transparent?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes I tried it gives me the same result

Comment: add the attribute elevation: 0.0 to your BottomNavigationBar, what you're seeing is a shadow because the elevation is 8.0 default. also you can just add the attribute background: Colors.transparent instead of wrapping your BottomNavigationBar with a Theme Widget

Comment: @EdwynZN  it was solved but the back ground is still white

Comment: if you set its color to transparent and the Scaffold to white it shows the Scaffold backgroundColor, or what color were you expecting?

Comment: @EdwynZN I am expecting that should show the grid lists or the contents instead of white color

Comment: in that case use the extendBody: true attribute of scaffold and put the BottomNavigationBar in the bottomNavigationBar attribute of scaffold instead of the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the futurebuilder outside the scaffold, not inside the body, because you really want to change the whole page

```
return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const SizedBox();
        } else 
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
            extendBody: true, //the body of the scaffold is shown behind the bottomNavigationBar
            appBar: AppBar( //use an AppBar widget instead of the one you created
              centerTitle: true, //this centers the title, in this case the image
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: null,
              ), //the button of the left
              title: Padding( //your image
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
              actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: AppTheme.dark_grey), //this change the theme of the action buttons, the one at the right
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                   icon: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
                   onPressed: () {
                     setState(() {
                       multiple = !multiple;
                     });
                  },
               )
             ],
            ),
            body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => Properties(),
              child: PropertiesGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
            ),
           bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
             backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //no color
             elevation: 0.0, // no shadow
             currentIndex: 0,
             items: [
               BottomNavigationBarItem(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                 title: Text('Map')),
               BottomNavigationBarItem(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.line_style),
                 title: Text('List')),
               BottomNavigationBarItem(
                 icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('Add Property'))
             ],
           ),
          )
        }
    );
```

you had a second future builder inside with the same future, which is irrelevant because you already had the value in the first one so I deleted it. when the future is waiting and there is no data, it will show a sizedBox() like you wanted, when the future is complete it will build the scaffold and you can use its parameters to build your page with tha appbar and BottomNavigationBarItem where it should be

UPDATE

I changed the appbar with the widget AppBar() that the scaffold expects (it expects one that implements a PreferredSizeWidget Class)

```
Widget appBar() {
    return SizedBox(....);
  }
```

This widget you created uses a SizedBox as the first widget in the treee, which doesn't implement that class, so it gives you the error, It's preferred to use the one that flutter gives you out of the box at first, and later you can create your own extending PreferredSizeWidget (if you need to implement something different) when you understood how it works

Comment: thanks a lot for your support but I wish to tell me how can I silve this problem `type 'SizedBox' is not a subtype of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'`, I found this I paste your code instead of old return code :)

Comment: I updated my answer, I used your Widget appBar() in the appbar attribute, but it expects an AppBar() Widget that implements a PreferredSizeWidget, your widget appBar() used a SizedBox, which doesn't implement it, so I change it. For more information about how to use all the attributes of the scaffold and the expected widgets check out https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material